# How does COM work?

Tags: c#, windows, com, clr

I have a dll that is allegedly a COM object. I'm trying to understand how exactly is the CLR able to figure out which function to call when no export function is available in the dll (I checked using depends).

```
  [Guid("DEADBEEF....")]
  [TypeLibType(...)]
  [ComImport]
  public interface ISomething
  {
    [DispId(1)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
    object DoSomething([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch), In] object something);
```

}

In here and I checked the MSIL there is no information about what address or function name, or offset it is located at.

Furthermore, there seems to be no information about how an object is layed out so its vtable pointer is passed, etc.

What magic is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From (unmanaged) code, one would use LoadTypeLib/LoadTypeLibEx on the "type library" file associated with the COM object. Quite commonly, that's the EXE or DLL registered for the COM object itself (but it could also be a standalone TLB file, a foreign type library etc). The documentation for LoadTypeLib has further pointers at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027(v=vs.85).aspx.

Once the ITypeLib/ITypeLib2 type library interface is obtained, it provides all the COM object info, including interfaces, vtable layout, prototypes etc. Full documentation is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221549(v=vs.85).aspx.

An example of LoadTypeLib in action is the OLE/COM Object Viewer provided with most versions of Visual Studio, which can essentially decompile a given type library back to an IDL. I can't post more than 2 URLs, but lookup https-//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx.

In managed code, the compiler does the importing of the type library transparently, though behind the scenes it's doing basically the same work as the OLE/COM Viewer, plus adding the necessary managed wrappers. See https-//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwzy44e4(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

Comment: thanks, does this theoretically can (even as a hack) that I could generate equivalent MSIL that calls into this stuff without runtime help? I.e. could I make the COM calls into simple P/Invokes through some mechanism, even if manual

Comment: Theoretically, I guess some combination of unsafe and P/Invoke could duplicate almost any C code incuding the OLE-from-C example at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181473. So, yes, technically you could. Don't know why you'd even contemplate doing it, though. You say "without runtime help" but also tag your question as C#/CLR. The framework already has all COM runtime support loaded already, so there is no penalty/overhead whatsoever in using it (but there would be much self-inflicted pain in *not* using it).

Comment: that is a fantastic idea, obviously COM can be called from C, so that's a natural entry point in the code. Thanks so much, you've made my day.